# <canvas> element twice as slow in OS X WebView compared to Safari 6

Tags: macos, cocoa, canvas, webview, safari

I have a WebView (OS X) loading a html file with just a canvas element that I want to do some drawing on.

Unexpectedly the frame rate is about 50% when in a WebView compared to just opening the file in Safari.

To test this further I ran [this canvas benchmark](http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/asteroidsbench/) with the same results:

**Safari**
Benchmark Score: 3652
Average FPS: 77

**WebView**
Benchmark Score: 1733
Average FPS: 37

And this doesn't seem to be related to JavaScript. Running the [Octane JavaScript Benchmark](http://octane-benchmark.googlecode.com/svn/latest/index.html) I get almost the same score in WebView and Safari.

[Here's a demo project](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/368222/WebView%20%26%20Canvas.zip) if you wanna try it out yourself. Just pick what test you wanna run in the AppDelegate.m.

I was under the impression Safari was using the same WebView we developers use? Does anybody know why rendering a canvas is so slow in a WebView and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to figure this out? Any alternative?

Comment: Nope. I ended up skipping the web view approach for a native OS X app.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable optimized rendering by setting the defaults of your application that uses the webview. similar to enabling the WebDeveloperExtras you can use `defaults write` to enable the accelerated canvas rendering. for me the following flags improved the performance:

```
defaults write <bundle.id> WebKitAccelerated2dCanvasEnabled -bool true
defaults write <bundle.id> WebKitAcceleratedDrawingEnabled -bool true
defaults write <bundle.id> WebKitCanvasUsesAcceleratedDrawing -bool true
```

Alternatively you can add the private methods to the `WebPreferences` interface:

```
@interface WebPreferences (WebPrivate)
...
- (BOOL)accelerated2dCanvasEnabled;
- (void)setAccelerated2dCanvasEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;

- (BOOL)acceleratedDrawingEnabled;
- (void)setAcceleratedDrawingEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;

- (BOOL)canvasUsesAcceleratedDrawing;
- (void)setCanvasUsesAcceleratedDrawing:(BOOL)enabled;

- (BOOL)acceleratedCompositingEnabled;
- (void)setAcceleratedCompositingEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;
...
@end
```

and then use it programmatically:

```
WebPreferences* prefs = [webView preferences];
[prefs setAccelerated2dCanvasEnabled:YES];
[prefs setAcceleratedDrawingEnabled:YES];
[prefs setCanvasUsesAcceleratedDrawing:YES];
[prefs setAcceleratedCompositingEnabled:YES];
[webView setPreferences:prefs];
```